# Filtering Large list (>5000) with two columns with or condition not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to use the below URI to retrieve items from a SharePoint Online list.

https://Site/_api/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items?$select=Id&$filter=(column1 eq 1 or column2 eq 1)&$top=5000

Basically I'm trying to filter a list using yes/no columns (both columns are indexed) using or condition. The above URI returns list view threshold error even though it does not return more than 10 items. If I use "and" it will work, but that doesn't serve the purpose.

Using OR condition against large list is not permitted? can any one share suggestions or workaround?

Thanks